# Some Google Analytics events sent through Measurement Protocol disappearing after a day

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

As of September 10, 2019, we are seeing some of the events we send to Google Analytics for multiple accounts register in Real Time events then show in Events Overview and then after about 24 hours they just disappear. Other events that are sent the same way do not disappear. We've tried resending the disappearing events, and those events end up disappearing again at around 1 day. Any insight as to what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated because my next stop might be the loony bin.

At first we thought the events weren't actually getting to Analytics, so we built out improvements to track the response status of each request we make. After we discovered that it wasn't a problem with the events reaching Analytics we investigated whether or not there were filters in place that were blocking the events. That was not the case. We got access to certain client accounts and watched as the events came in Real Time events and then appeared in Events Overview.

Once we confirmed that the events were in fact getting to Analytics, we resent ones that we thought didn't make it since they weren't in Analytics. Those resent events appeared in both Real Time events and Events Overview. A day later we discovered that the events were no longer there.

We have unsuccessfully tried to find the difference between the events that stick and the events that disappear. We even thought that maybe there were gclid errors and when the gclids were sent over to AdWords from Analytics something would error and then Analytics would remove the events associated to the gclid. We have since sent the gclids as conversions straight to AdWords without any issues.

Here are two GET requests that we have made to the same Analytics account that have produced one event that stuck and one that disappeared.

Event sent on 09/09/19 still in Analytics:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid={account_id}&cid=6EFD2E9B-648D-4142-9500-9CBEECFC31F8&ec=call&ea=Google+-+Paid&el=&ev=33&aip=1&geoid=AU&cn=&cs=Google+-+Paid&cm=cpc&ck=&sn=&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F76.0.3809.132+Safari%2F537.36&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&gclid={gclid}
```

Event originally sent on 09/12/19 that has disappeared each time it has been sent:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid={account_id}&cid=2F884E20-7FEE-436E-B127-6430F0B7BBA9&ec=call&ea=Google+-+Paid&el=&ev=205&aip=1&geoid=AU&cn=&cs=Google+-+Paid&cm=cpc&ck=&sn=&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F76.0.3809.132+Safari%2F537.36&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&gclid={gclid}
```

We expect all events to not disappear like they didn't prior to September 10, 2019.

Comment: I tried 2 days ago but I still have both events in Analytics (which are practically the same).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with conversions disappearing once tracked and visualised. I changed attribution model in GA4 from the ¨Last click¨ to the ¨Data-Driven-recommended¨ and automatically all lost conversions appeared in the reports again, and I can confirm that they are correct as we track them with CRM tool as the source of truth.